# Как сделать однообразное оформление сообщений от бота для ПК и мобильных устройств в моноширинном стиле?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram-3.x

Написал бота для класса в школе, он выдает расписание и меню.

Так выглядит сообщение на ПК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так на телефоне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При формировании текста каждую строку оборачиваю в теги `<code> и </code>`

Очевидно, что размеры экранов и количество максимальных символов в строке для ПК и телефона отличаются, но почему настолько разное оформление?

И вопросы:

1. Можно ли изменять размер шрифта для сообщений под телефон (скорее всего нет, но спрошу на всякий)?
2. Можно ли как-то генерировать ответ бота в виде картинки чтобы отправить ее пользователю?
3. Вообще каким образом решить проблему с размещением текста на мобильных устройствах?
4. У ChatGPT бота, например, есть такое оформление сообщений:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как оно достигается? Разные цвета, затемненный фон, одинаковое оформление под телефон и ПК. Причем можно копировать как весь код, так и его часть в текстовом виде.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это работает только с языками программирования, но вы можете попробовать написать в каждой строчке # (но выглядеть будет странно)

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, размер шрифта не меняется и зависит от используемого устройства
2. Если у вас есть это расписание в HTML, то можно преобразовывать в картинку. Либо можете выдавать ее в виде [Мини-приложения](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps)
3. Только соблюдать количество символов в строке
4. Использовать `HTML` или `Markdown` форматирование:

MarkdownV2:

> ````
> ```python
> тут код Python, который будет окрашен как в вашем примере
> ```
> ````

HTML:

> <pre><code class="language-python">тут код Python, который будет окрашен как в вашем примере</code></pre>

Comment: Спасибо! А таблицу в ответ бота нельзя вставить в html? Я пытался, у меня не работало ((